# How can you customize only the dateformat of CultureInfos?

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo, iformatprovider

I want to create a `IFormatProvider` such that number formatting works like it does in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but date formatting works customized to a short date.

Such that `AnyStringDoubleDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` results in a long dateformat for dates, which I don't want, but all other formats are fine already.

Is there a way to change this behavior for dates?
I can only use `String.ToString()`.

Comment: Maybe you could use `AnyStringDoubleDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)`.

Comment: As ShortDatePattern is a string, this tells me it cant be converted to IFormatProvider.

Comment: You can make your own CultureInfo with `Dim ci = new CultureInfo("")` (which takes its settings from InvariantCulture) and then customise whichever parts of `ci` you need to.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Of what type is `AnyStringDoubleDate`? You cannot format a string. Formatting is involved when converting a non-string value to a string. Therefore, you must start with a `System.DateTime` (having the alias `Date` in VB). Then you can specify a format by using this overload of [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring):

```vb
Public Function ToString (format As String, provider As IFormatProvider) As 
String
```

Then you can write:

```vb
Dim s  As String
Dim dt As Date

dt = ...
s = dt.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)  ' ==> 08/17/2000
' OR
s = dt.ToString("g", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)  ' ==> 08/17/2000 16:32
```

Or use any other [Standard date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or a [Custom date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: So what is String.ToString(IFormatProvider) for? I thought that formats a string

Comment: Yes it does, but uses a default date format. The overload above allows you to specify both, the desired format and a culture specific format provider. Don't confuse the two. The first parameter allows you to specify if you want a short date, a long date, a time only, a week name, etc. where as the second parameter specifies the culture specific aspects like the date or time separators used, the language of the month names etc.